# How to center align multiple span in div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to display tags in the form of span element within a div which looks something like this.

[image]

The tags are center aligned here, but when the tags shift to the next line/row, then the below row is not center aligned.

[image]

I want to set both the rows to be center aligned.

Below is the ReactJS code for the same:

```
const styles = {
  tag: {
    border: "1px solid #ffffff",
    borderRadius: "10%",
    padding: 2,
    margin: "2px"
  },
  tagsWrapper: {
    width: "100%",
    padding: "5px",
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  }
};

<div style={styles.tagsWrapper}>
   <div
     style={{
       margin: "0px auto",
       display: "flex",
       flexWrap: "wrap"
     }}>
     {this.props.tags.map((tag, index) => {
       if (tag.selected)
         return (
           <span key={index} style={styles.tag}>
             {tag.label}
           </span>
         );
       else return null;
     })}
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried to find the solution but couldn't find any.

Comment: use text-align: center on div

Comment: Seeming as this question isn't *really* about React, more about HTML/CSS, it may be better to simply post your HTML output and the CSS. You will probably get more responses as some people who know HTML/CSS will not know React.

Comment: @sumitchauhan It didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using flexbox use

`justify-content:center`

...on the wrapper. This should be what you are after.

> justify-content: center;     /* Pack items around the center */
>
> <sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)</sup>

Comment: Worked perfectly.